# openldap: failed to add user with ldapadd

Tags: ldap, openldap

My user ldif file look like that:

``` dn: uid=jack,ou=people,cn=Jack Wallen,dc=examplem,dc=com
uid: jack
cn: Jack Wallen
objectClass: person
sn: Wallen
UserPassword: 123456
``
dn: uid=sheldon,ou=people,cn=Sheldon Cooper,dc=examplem,dc=com
uid: sheldon
cn: Sheldon Cooper
objectClass: person
sn: Cooper
UserPassword: 1234567 ```

but when I'm trying to add it with

```
ldapadd -x -D "cn=Manager,dc=examplem,dc=com" -v -w secret -f ~/tmp/user.ldif
```

I get

```
adding new entry "uid=jack,ou=people,cn=Jack Wallen,dc=examplem,dc=com"
ldap_add: Type or value exists (20)
    additional info: objectClass: value #0 provided more than once
```

Why? what is my mistake

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

an empty line is not allowed in ldif files